# Keep getting empty Map while it should contain data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Well, I've been struggling with this for a while now (or it's about my head that's just going to explode...). I'm coding a simple app in Node.js, that allows users to assign lucky shots (flukes) to students. The functionality I have a problem with is getting a student=>fluke points map.

I'm using Express 4.15.5 and Mongoose 5.0.1.

This is my code:

```
    router.get('/list', (request, response) => {
      Fluke
        .find({})
        .then((flukes) => {
          response.render('pages/fluke/list', { tableData: aggregateStudentsWithFlukes(flukes) })
        })
     })

    function aggregateStudentsWithFlukes(flukes) {
        let result = new Map()

        flukes.forEach((fluke) => {
          let points = fluke.acquiredPoints

          Student
            .findById(fluke.student)
            .then((student) => {
              let studentName = getStudentName(student.name, student.surname)

              if (result.has(studentName))
                result.get(studentName).push(points) /* Exists, push points */
              else
                result.set(studentName, [points]) /* Doesn't exist, create new one */
            })
        })

        return result
    }
```

I want the map to look like this:

```
{
  'Name Surname': [25, 15, 30]
  ...more entries...
}
```

But I keep on getting an empty map. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have seems correct, I tried simulating something similar and it works perfectly see code below.

```
function populatePoints(name, point) {
  let result = new Map();

  if (result.has(name)) {
    result.get(name).push(point)
  } else {
    result.set(name, [point])
  }
  return result
}

console.log(populatePoints('John Doe', 22));
console.log(populatePoints('John Doe', 22));
console.log(populatePoints('Jenny Doe', 29));
```

However, your `promise` hasn't resolved before your `return result` gets called which is why you're getting an empty object.

So try to move your `return` statement into the `Student.findById(fluke.student).then((student)` promise

More like this

```
Student
     .findById(fluke.student)
     .then((student) => {
       let studentName = getStudentName(student.name, student.surname)
       if (result.has(studentName)) {
         result.get(studentName).push(points) /* Exists, push points */   
       } else {
         result.set(studentName, [points])
       } 
       return result;
      })
```